# Typedef in C, but a different way

Tags: c, typedef

I am aware of the standard way to define a structure in C. But, in analogy with this:

```c
// <typedef structureName alias>
typedef unsigned long int u_int32
```

I was expecting this to work too:

```c
struct myStr {char name[100]; float avgProb; int severity;};
typedef myStr ms;
myStr ms = {name:"hell", avgProb:50.0, severity:5,};
printf("myR %f", ms.avgProb);
```

Is it just not possible to do it or I am missing something?

Comment: Side note: this syntax for designated initializers in C is non-standard and obsolete. See <https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=88144>.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it just not possible to do it or I am missing something?

You simply need to learn C syntax and basics before coding

```
  struct myStr {char name[100]; float avgProb; int severity;};
  typedef struct myStr ms;
  ms m = {.name = "hell", .avgProb = 50.0, .severity = 5,};
  printf("myR %f", m.avgProb);
```

Or simply

```
typedef struct 
{
    char name[100]; 
    float avgProb; 
    int severity;
}myStr;

  myStr m = {.name = "hell", .avgProb = 50.0, .severity = 5,};
  printf("myR %f", m.avgProb);
```

Some good resources:
[The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: but why is **struct** repeated

Comment: @Minsky Because it is `struct`. As I wrote - start from the C book and learn C basics

Comment: I won't but thanks. Good for removing the rude part from the post.

Comment: @Minsky *"`I won't`"* . There is no other way. You need to learn some basic stuff first. Books are the best learning resources

Comment: @Minsky If you don’t want to learn, then don’t post questions.

Answer (score 3):

`struct myStr {...};` doesn't define `myStr` as a type in C (unlike in C++).  It defines `struct myStr` as a type.
If you want myStr to be a typedef for the defined `struct myStr` type, you need to say that

```
typedef struct myStr myStr;
```

If you always want such a `typedef`, you can create a macro for it:

```
#define TYPEDEFED_STRUCT(NAME) typedef struct NAME NAME; struct NAME
TYPEDEFED_STRUCT(myStr){ ... }
```

This behavior is due to how C separates *normal* and *tag* *namespaces*.

As a consequence of that, you can have both a function named
e.g., `stat` and a structure tagged stat (`struct stat`) and they don't conflict.
(Unix has a function named stat whose prototype is `int stat(char const*, struct stat*);`).

Interestingly since standardization, the tag namespace is shared between `struct` tags, `union` tags, and `enum` tags, so once you have `struct stat`, then even though you can have `int stat();`, defining a `union stat` or an `enum stat` would create conflicts with the `struct stat` (as theres's only one namespace for `struct`s, `union`s, and `enum`s).

Comment: Ugh. That macro gives me the creeps.

Comment: This macro ..... something absolutely horrible.

Comment: @klutt It's kind of an ugly hack as many/most macros are, but when you want C++ style autotypefing in C, it gets the job done :).

Comment: `t defines struct myStr as a type` - no it does not. `myStruc` is a structure **tag**

Comment: @0___________ after `struct myStr {...}`, `struct myStr` is a type.

Comment: @PSkocik There are degrees in hell... :D

Answer (score 3):

> I was expecting this to work also:
>     `typedef myStr ms;`
> Is it just not possible to do it or I am missing something?

It's possible, but what you're doing there isn't it.  (In a sense you're [begging the question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question).)

Your attempt

```
typedef myStr ms;
```

would work *if `myStr` were already a typedef name.*  But of course it's not, yet.

When you declare a structure like

```
struct myStr {char name[100]; float avgProb; int severity;};
```

its full, official name (the name on its birth certificate, so to speak) is `struct myStr`.

A lot of programmers (especially if they've seen how "easy" it is in C++) wish that their structures had single names, wish that they didn't have to keep slinging that `struct` keyword around.  And you can certainly do that, by declaring a typedef.  *But*, when you declare this typedef, it has to be in terms of the full, official, existing name of the type.  So it's

```
typedef struct myStr ms;
```

where we can break that down as

```
typedef struct myStr ms;
\_____/ \__________/ \/
keyword   old name   new
                     name
```

---

You asked about C, but I suspect your thinking here has been influenced by something you may have heard abut C++.
Things are a little different in C++, and when you say

```
struct myStr {char name[100]; float avgProb; int severity;};
```

it not only declares a structure `struct myStr`, *it also implicitly creates a typedef at the same time*.  It's as if you had also said

```
typedef struct myStr myStr;
```

So now (in C++) you can either say

```
struct myStr struct1 = { "Fred", 1.2, 3 };
```

or

```
myStr struct1 = { "Barney", 4.5, 6 };
```

(And, in case you're wondering, yes: the typedef name is exactly the same as the structure name, but it turns out that's okay, and not ambiguous.)

So, in C++, you *could* say

```
typedef myStr ms;
```

if you wanted to give your structure a second, shorter name.  Although, in C++, you wouldn't really need to do that, either, because you could just give it that shorter name to begin with:

```
struct ms {char name[100]; float avgProb; int severity;};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
struct myStr {...};
```

This defines a struct and also a *tag* name for it. These tags have their own namespace, but they must be always preceded by `struct`.

```
struct my {...};
```

therefore is enough; as in `sizeof(struct my)`.

For the typedef:

```
typedef struct my myStr;
```

Now `myStr` is of `struct my` type. I would prefer `my_t`, even though the `_t` is reserved.

Both at once is also possible:

```
typedef struct my {...} myStr;
```

Without `typedef`, `myStr` would be a `struct my` itself. With, it defines a new name for that type.

Answer (score 0):

You declared type specifier `struct myStr`.

```
struct myStr {char name[100]; float avgProb; int severity;};
```

Thus in this typedef declaration

```
typedef myStr ms;
```

the name `myStr` is undefined. To refer to the name `myStr` you need to precede it with the keyword `struct` like `struct myStr`.

You have to write

```
typedef struct myStr ms;
```

So now `ms` becomes a type specifier that is an alias for the type specifier `struct myStr`..

Alternatively you may rewrite the typedef declaration also the following way

```
struct myStr typedef me;
```

This declaration and the initializer list are incorrect.

```
myStr ms = {name:"hell", avgProb:50.0, severity:5,};
```

You need to write for example

```
ms s = { .name = "hell", .avgProb = 50.0, .severity = 5,};
```

or

```
ms s = { "hell", 50.0, 5,};
```

Pay attention to that the last comma though may be present but is redundant.

If you wanted to have this declaration

```
myStr ms = { .name = "hell", .avgProb = 50.0, .severity = 5,};
```

then the typedef declaration should look like

```
typedef struct myStr myStr;
```

or

```
struct myStr typedef myStr;
```